# TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<MyObject>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MyObject>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I decided to upgrade from Angular 4.x to Angular 6.0 using official Angular upgrade guide. After fixing all switchMaps, mergeMaps and other imports which changed between RxJS 5 and RxJS 6 my app doesn't work anymore.Problem is somewhere in my `@Injectable()`, since I'm using custom HttpHeaders.

This is my current code, which was normaly working on previous Angular and RxJS versions.

**users.service.ts**

```
buildHeaders(): Observable<any> {
  if (!auth.enabled) {
    return from(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(new HttpHeaders());
    }));
  }

  return from(this.authService.getHeaders())
    .pipe(
      map(header => {
        return new HttpHeaders(header);
      }));
}

getUsers(id: number): Observable<MyObject> {
  const path = `${url}/Users/${id}`;

  return this.buildHeaders()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(headers => {
        return this.http.get<MyObject>(path, { 'headers': headers });
    }));
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? If I define result of `getUsers()` as `Observable<any>` it looks like it works. Also if I remove `buildHeaders()` function, error also dissapears. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Adding code, which was working before Angular/RxJS upgrade

```
buildHeaders(): Observable<any> {
  if (!auth.enabled) {
    return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(new HttpHeaders());
    }));
  }
  
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.getHeaders())
    .map(header => {
      return new HttpHeaders(header);
    });
}

getUsers(id: number): Observable<MyObject> {
  const path = `${url}/Users/${id}`;

  return this.buildHeaders()
    .mergeMap(headers => {
      return this.http.get<MyObject>(path, { 'headers': headers });
    });
}
```

EDIT 2:
After removing/commenting out

```
if (!auth.enabled) {
  return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(new HttpHeaders());
  }));
}
```

and changing return type to `Observable<HttpHeaders>` as [@JSmart523](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7158380/jsmart523) mentioned in comment, error seems to dissapear. Looks like something is wrong in that piece of code, eg. return type is wrong.

Comment: At what line is the error occurring?

Comment: It says in line, where `return this.buildHeaders()` is

Comment: Can we see what authService.getHeaders looks like?

Comment: I prefer not, if it isn't necessary. But that part did not change, its call to prepare Bearer token from auth service, and it returns `Promise`, if that information helps you.

Comment: Can I send it somewhere in private?

Comment: Just to verify, I have noticed in your code that some brackets are missing at the end of the function getUsers. Last line should be added this:

    return this.http.get<MyObject>(path, { 'headers': headers }) 
    }));

Comment: Could it be because you're using `from` instead of `of`? My theory is that from(promise) if the same as from(observable) which is why Typescript things that buildHeaders is returning an observable if observables.

Comment: @Shem I guess I made just mistake when copying, otherwise I guess I would get other build errors, or errors which would be present before upgrade.

Comment: @JSmart523 Looks like no, if I change `from` to `of` I get error in line, where I am calling `authService`. I will update my question now, with old code, which was working before Angular/RxJS update.

Comment: Okay. Change the return type of buildHeaders to `Observable<HttpHeaders>`. That will help reveal the problem.

Comment: @JSmart523 after that I get `Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpHeaders>'.  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders'.` error on whole return statement inside `if (!auth.enabled)` clause.

Comment: I'm guessing it's right but TypeScript isn't smart enough to realize it. I tried updating your code in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this...

```
buildHeaders(): Observable<HttpHeaders> {
  if (!auth.enabled) {
    return of(new HttpHeaders());
  } else {
    return from(this.authService.getHeaders()).pipe(
      map(header => new HttpHeaders(header))
    );
  }
}
```

`map` as a method of observables has been deprecated. Instead, operators are standalone functions that are used as arguments within the `pipe` method of observables.

You'll have to import `of` and `from` from 'rxjs', and import `map` from 'rxjs/operators'. `of` returns an observable that emits the parameter. `from` returns an observable that emits the "contents" of the parameter... usually used to unpack arrays and promises..